# Inappropriate Event handler error

Tags: c#, xaml

Can you explain me please, why appears this error when i compiled the program?

This example is from a book.

Code c#:

```
private void lst_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lst.SelectedItem == null) return;
        txtSelection.Text = String.Format(
        "You chose item at position {0}.\r\nChecked state is {1}.",
        lst.SelectedIndex,
        ((CheckBox)lst.SelectedItem).IsChecked);
    }
```

Code xaml:

```
    <ListBox Name="lst" SelectionChanged="lst_SelectionChanged"
CheckBox.Click="lst_SelectionChanged">
        <CheckBox Margin="3">Option 1</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="3">Option 2</CheckBox>
        <TextBox Name="txtSelection" Width="200" ></TextBox>
    </ListBox>
```

This is the error:

```
"No overload for 'lst_SelectionChanged' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler'"
```

Comment: The `CheckBox.Click` event doesn't match the signature `lst_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)` (specifically, the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` part). Consider adding another event handler which matches the CheckBox.Click handler, moving the body of the `lst_SelectionChanged` event to another method (probably a parameterless method) and have both event handlers invoke this new parameterless method. That is: `private void lst_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) { DoTheStuff(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Change XAML to following:
    
    `<ListBox Name="lst" SelectionChanged="lst_SelectionChanged">
        <CheckBox Margin="3">Option 1</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="3">Option 2</CheckBox>
        <TextBox Name="txtSelection" Width="200" ></TextBox>
    </ListBox>`